# What is the term for these piles of tiles on top of a roof?

Tags: terminology

[image: hullo]

What is the term for these piles of tiles on top of a roof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kind of roof ornament. I can't tell what exactly it is from your photo, but most of them are [吻兽](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/%E5%90%BB%E5%85%BD). It is a common roof ornament in ancient Chinese architectural.